# How to shorten a table pagination with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am working on a jQuery table pagination. The idea is to show the pagination while the table has many rows.

I have managed to show all the pagination links including Previous and Next links, but I further want ellipsis(...) to show-up and shorten the pagination links as given below.

Here's a quick example to make it clear. This is what I have now:

> Pages: 1 2 3 4 [5] 6 7 8 9 10 11

This is what I want to achieve:

> Pages: ... 4 [5] 6 ...

**PS:** The code should use bootstrap styling. Please help.

The code :

```js
$.fn.pageMe = function(opts){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            perPage: 7,
            showPrevNext: false,
            hidePageNumbers: false
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

    var listElement = $this;
    var perPage = settings.perPage;
    var children = listElement.children();
    var pager = $('.pager');

    if (typeof settings.childSelector!="undefined") {
        children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
    }

    if (typeof settings.pagerSelector!="undefined") {
        pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
    }

    var numItems = children.size();
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);

    pager.data("curr",0);

    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }
      
    var curr = 0;
    while(numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers==false)){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
        curr++;

    }
      
    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }

    pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
    pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
    if (numPages<=1) {
        pager.find('.next_link').hide();
    }
      pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");

    children.hide();
    children.slice(0, perPage).show();

    pager.find('li .page_link').click(function(){
        var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf()-1;
        goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function(){
        previous();
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .next_link').click(function(){
        next();
        return false;
    });

    function previous(){
        var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }

    function next(){
        goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }

    function goTo(page){
        var startAt = page * perPage,
            endOn = startAt + perPage;

        children.css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();

        if (page>=1) {
            pager.find('.prev_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
        }

        if (page<(numPages-1)) {
            pager.find('.next_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.next_link').hide();
        }

        pager.data("curr",page);
       pager.children().removeClass("active");
        pager.children().eq(page+1).addClass("active");

    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/1.4.0/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Table heading</th>
              <th>Table heading</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="myTable">
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="success">
              <td>5</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>8</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>9</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>15</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>16</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>17</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>18</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>19</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>20</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>21</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>

            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I try to modify this function but without result

```js
    var curr = 0;
    while(numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers==false)){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
        curr++;

    }
```

Comment: is the pagination working for you ? because there is no function called as `size()` in `var numItems = children.size();` it should be `var numItems = children.length;`

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa tha problem is not in the pagination, it's work without any problem. || the problem in number ( pagination ) they give me all pages, but I want to shorten it from `Pages : 1 - 2 - 3 - [4] - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 ` coming like this `Pages : ... - 3 - [4] - 5 ... `, a small example

Comment: Ya working on it ..

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Thanks because I try a lot to find the result but without any result

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Any solution ? I try to fix it all day without result

Comment: Did Kiran Shakya's **modified** answer not work ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa He modify and it's work correctly, thank to you and thanks to hem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to show ellipsis as you asked. But, currently it only works when you click on any one of the pagination link. It will be easy for you to make ellipsis show up before clicking, once you know the idea. I leave that step up to you and head straight to brief what I have done.

1. Search for the comment `// Added class and id in li start` in the following code to see first changes. What it does is clearly mentioned in the comment. It adds id and class for future reference.
2. Search for the comment `// Added few lines from here start` in the following code to see few additional codes. Firstly we hide all the li except previous and next links and also remove ellipsis if present, secondly we show three pagination links, thirdly we check if only two links are shown instead of three and made sure three of them are shown and finally we show ellipsis if pages are more than three.

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the code to work with bootstrap css and made it start with ellipsis for you. Hope you are satisfied.

```js
$.fn.pageMe = function(opts) {
  var $this = this,
    defaults = {
      perPage: 7,
      showPrevNext: false,
      hidePageNumbers: false
    },
    settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

  var listElement = $this;
  var perPage = settings.perPage;
  var children = listElement.children();
  var pager = $('.pager');

  if (typeof settings.childSelector != "undefined") {
    children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
  }

  if (typeof settings.pagerSelector != "undefined") {
    pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
  }

  var numItems = children.size();
  var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems / perPage);

  pager.data("curr", 0);

  if (settings.showPrevNext) {
    $('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
  }

  var curr = 0;
  // Added class and id in li start
  while (numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers == false)) {
    $('<li id="pg' + (curr + 1) + '" class="pg"><a href="#" class="page_link">' + (curr + 1) + '</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    curr++;
  }
  // Added class and id in li end

  if (settings.showPrevNext) {
    $('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
  }

  pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
  pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
  if (numPages <= 1) {
    pager.find('.next_link').hide();
  }
  pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");

  children.hide();
  children.slice(0, perPage).show();
  if (numPages > 3) {
    $('.pg').hide();
    $('#pg1,#pg2,#pg3').show();
    $("#pg3").after($("<li class='ell'>").html("<span>...</span>"));
  }

  pager.find('li .page_link').click(function() {
    var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf() - 1;
    goTo(clickedPage, perPage);
    return false;
  });
  pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function() {
    previous();
    return false;
  });
  pager.find('li .next_link').click(function() {
    next();
    return false;
  });

  function previous() {
    var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;
    goTo(goToPage);
  }

  function next() {
    goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;
    goTo(goToPage);
  }

  function goTo(page) {
    var startAt = page * perPage,
      endOn = startAt + perPage;

    // Added few lines from here start

    $('.pg').hide();
    $(".ell").remove();
    var prevpg = $("#pg" + page).show();
    var currpg = $("#pg" + (page + 1)).show();
    var nextpg = $("#pg" + (page + 2)).show();
    if (prevpg.length == 0) nextpg = $("#pg" + (page + 3)).show();
    if (prevpg.length == 1 && nextpg.length == 0) {
      prevpg = $("#pg" + (page - 1)).show();
    }
    if (curr > 3) {
      if (page > 1) prevpg.before($("<li class='ell'>").html("<span>...</span>"));
      if (page < curr - 2) nextpg.after($("<li class='ell'>").html("<span>...</span>"));
    }
    currpg.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    // Added few lines till here end


    children.css('display', 'none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();

    if (page >= 1) {
      pager.find('.prev_link').show();
    } else {
      pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
    }

    if (page < (numPages - 1)) {
      pager.find('.next_link').show();
    } else {
      pager.find('.next_link').hide();
    }

    pager.data("curr", page);
    /*pager.children().removeClass("active");
    pager.children().eq(page + 1).addClass("active");*/

  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myTable').pageMe({
    pagerSelector: '#myPager',
    showPrevNext: true,
    hidePageNumbers: false,
    perPage: 4
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="myTable">
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr class="success">
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>

          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thers's a smal problem if you click in a page (for example 5) the 4 page is checked

Comment: Or the bootstrap make the problem ?

Comment: and the second problem is started with 6 pages and if you click in any page they changed to `1 - 2 - 3 ... >>`

Comment: That is because I was unaware you were writing the code for bootstrap. You can try running the code and see the result.

Comment: If I try the code without bootsrap it's just 1 problem is in the first show all page you need to click to see `<< .. 2 - [3] - [4] .. >>`

Comment: And If I try with bootstrap there's two problem, first it's the same, the second is all pagination style not working 
1-`If you click in button 4 for example the 3 is active [3] - 4`

Comment: Use that and show the result `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/1.4.0/assets/css/bootstrap.css">`

Comment: @saadsaad Check the answer now. It has been modified to meet your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your source is work! But maybe, You forgot to set the plugins:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/1.4.0/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: Yes It's work but is show all pages so a want to shorted a little

Comment: This answer has no attempt on answering the OP. OP expects ellipsis after three pagination links and adjust accordingly on different pages.